# Problemas con la Ruta en en Modelo de Laravel 7

Tags: controller, laravel-7, modelos

No suelo escribir en los foros, pero no sé que mas buscar.
Resulta que estoy construyendo un CRUD en Laravel 7 (es lo que me exige la empresa en donde trabajo, por eso no he avanzado a 8 u 9).

Y creé tanto el Modelo como el Controlador por consola.
Pero no me reconoce la ruta al modelo.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;


use app\actdtsActividades;


class ActividadControlador extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $actividad = new actdtsActividades;

        $arreglo =  array(
            'actsdts_nmb_nombre' => $request->nombreActividad,
            'actsdts_fch_inicio' => '20-2-2022',
            'usrdts_id' => 1,
            'acttpo_TipoActividad_acttpo_id'=>1
        );
           
        /*
        $actividad->actsdts_nmb_nombre = $request->nombreActividad;
        $actividad->actsdts_fch_inicio = $request->fecha;
        $actividad->usrdts_id = 1;
        $actividad->acttpo_TipoActividad_acttpo_id=1;
        $actividad->save();

        return redirect('Egresados')->with('Mensaje', 'Hola');
        */

        BD::table('actdts_datos de actividad')->insert($arreglo);
        return $request;
        //return redirect('Egresados')->with('Mensaje', $request);
    }
}
```

Entonces, no sé que hacer, es como si en la carpeta app no existiera `actdtsActividades` y cuando lo saqué para probar directamente me registra el mismo error para DB.

Me habra faltado correr algo?

Corrí `composer dump-autoload`
y `npm run dev` pero nada arregló mi error y me siento varada hace días.

Este es mi error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Desde ya muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cambie y sigue el mismo error.

Comment: El error que me sale es: Error
Class 'app\actdtsActividades' not found

Comment: El namespace es `App` con mayúscula, pero pusiste `use app\actdtsActividades;` con minúscula.

Comment: *"Lo cambie y sigue el mismo error"* -> en la segunda imagen que muestras se sigue viendo `app` con minúscula. Para que quede claro, cambia `use app\actdtsActividades;` por  `use App\actdtsActividades;`. Si aún así no encuentra la clase, publica el código de la clase `actdtsActividades`